# nginx rewrite for trailing slash and php not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I want all the wildcard folder and url to show 404.php.
Below code works for following

```
domain.com/wildcard.html
domain.com/wildcard
```

but it is not working for following

```
domain.com/wildcard.php
domain.com/wildcard/
```

I get some other `File not found.` error for php and `404 Not Found nginx`  error for folder with trailing slash.It is supposed to show my 404.php

```
location ~* / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @vishnu;
    rewrite ^(.*?)$ /404.php last;

}
```